# BETWEEN operator for string in LINQ to SQL query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

```
from p in table
where ID == 201
&& date => 20160601
&& date <= 20160901
select {ID, name};
q.Dump();
```

The date in the database is in string simple format. 
I am trying to convert a SQL query to LINQ. In SQL, BETWEEN operator is being used to select values within a given range. But, BETWEEN can't be used with LINQ statement, so I am getting an error which says => cannot be applied to operands of type string and int for the date field. Any help would be appropriated. I tried the DateTime, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: it's not `=>` but `>=`. `=>` is for lambdas.

Comment: Do you mean like this? date =>.20160601

Comment: Yes, that should be  `date >= 20160601`

Comment: it's not working. Getting the same error. >= cannot be applied to string or int in LINQ

Comment: Which means `date`  is a string right now. You will have to parse it to get an integer or cast `20160601` so it's a string. Normaly you would use [`Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) class for such a task to avoid problem like that one

Comment: How should I parse it? I found DateTime.ParseExact. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, as long as you provide the correct format. But you will need to parse both `date` (as it seems to be a string) and your numbers.

Comment: If you want the query to translate to SQL, you need to use `Convert.ToDateTime` instead of `DateTime.Parse`.

Answer (score 1):

Since LINQ to Entities doesn't support `Convert.ToDateTime` (why not?) and your date formats are in a reasonable string format, you can compare as strings:

```
from p in table
where ID == 201
&& date.CompareTo("20160601") >= 0
&& date.CompareTo("20160901") <= 0
select { ID, name };
```

Comment: I am getting an error when I try to run it using convert.ToDateTime. "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: That's disappointing - LINQ to SQL handles it just fine... answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this working code:

```
var q = from p in table
where p.ID == 201
&& p.date >= DateTime.ParseExact("20160601", "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
&& p.date <= DateTime.ParseExact("20160901", "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
select p;
q.Dump();
```